# Docker - How to list volume Names - simple way

Tags: docker

So when you *docker run*, it will create automatically volumes for your container. When you only have one container on your host its easy to find which volumes have been created.

```
docker volume ls
```

Returns :

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               21625133cc5dde5eae34b5ee85c6c26c15d4c5bb0847f1fd3629a33faa5084ce
local               ad134a6d0130f11ad5b3af9340205eb712718397ece3cfaf8adf5b08abe0362a
local               e425b2a143ecb1ca69aaf15ea25bdc232178bea9662dc77bbe0c2c630f452874
```

But when you ask docker inspect :

```
docker inspect --format='{{json .Mounts}}{{ .Name}}' $INSTANCE_ID | jq
```

I'll get :

```
[
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/admin/cobbler-dkr/etc/cobbler/settings",
    "Destination": "/etc/cobbler/settings",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/admin/cobbler-dkr/var/www/cobbler/links",
    "Destination": "/var/www/cobbler/links",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "21625133cc5dde5eae34b5ee85c6c26c15d4c5bb0847f1fd3629a33faa5084ce",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/21625133cc5dde5eae34b5ee85c6c26c15d4c5bb0847f1fd3629a33faa5084ce/_data",
    "Destination": "“/sys/fs/cgroup”",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/admin/cobbler-dkr/var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror",
    "Destination": "/var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "e425b2a143ecb1ca69aaf15ea25bdc232178bea9662dc77bbe0c2c630f452874",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/e425b2a143ecb1ca69aaf15ea25bdc232178bea9662dc77bbe0c2c630f452874/_data",
    "Destination": "]",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
    "Destination": "/sys/fs/cgroup",
    "Mode": "ro",
    "RW": false,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/admin/cobbler-dkr/dist/centos",
    "Destination": "/mnt",
    "Mode": "ro",
    "RW": false,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/admin/cobbler-dkr/var/lib/cobbler/config",
    "Destination": "/var/lib/cobbler/config",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/admin/cobbler-dkr/var/lib/tftpboot",
    "Destination": "/var/lib/tftpboot",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/admin/cobbler-dkr/etc/cobbler/dhcp.template",
    "Destination": "/etc/cobbler/dhcp.template",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/admin/cobbler-dkr/var/www/cobbler/images",
    "Destination": "/var/www/cobbler/images",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "ad134a6d0130f11ad5b3af9340205eb712718397ece3cfaf8adf5b08abe0362a",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/ad134a6d0130f11ad5b3af9340205eb712718397ece3cfaf8adf5b08abe0362a/_data",
    "Destination": "[",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  }
]
```

I tried to list and the volume Names thanks to *range*:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ range .Mounts }}{{if eq .Type "volume" }}{{ .Name}}{{end}}{{ end }}' 33623ebfece7
```

But I got something odd, no spaces seems to appear:

```
e425b2a143ecb1ca69aaf15ea25bdc232178bea9662dc77bbe0c2c630f452874ad134a6d0130f11ad5b3af9340205eb712718397ece3cfaf8adf5b08abe0362a21625133cc5dde5eae34b5ee85c6c26c15d4c5bb0847f1fd3629a33faa5084ce
```

My last try was to grep the Raw answer :

```
docker inspect --format='{{json .Mounts}}{{ .Name}}' 33623ebfece7 | jq | grep '"Name":'
```

Returned :

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
"Name": "e425b2a143ecb1ca69aaf15ea25bdc232178bea9662dc77bbe0c2c630f452874",
"Name": "ad134a6d0130f11ad5b3af9340205eb712718397ece3cfaf8adf5b08abe0362a",
"Name": "21625133cc5dde5eae34b5ee85c6c26c15d4c5bb0847f1fd3629a33faa5084ce",
```

Now I got the names, but I think I'm not taking the simpler way to get a list of my volumes deployed for the container.

The intention is to delete them after I delete my container so I can start from a fresh instance.
I know there is *prune* but I don't want to delete all unused docker volumes on later purpose, just want a clean way to teardown my container.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're manually deleting the containers, [`docker rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) has an option for this:

> `--volumes`, `-v`: Remove anonymous volumes associated with the container

Similarly, if Docker Compose manages your application, [`docker-compose down -v`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) will delete anonymous volumes (along with every other volume declared in the `docker-compose.yml` file).

The `docker inspect` output you show suggests this is ultimately being caused by an incorrect line in your Dockerfile; perhaps a line like

```sh
# (1) This VOLUME is unnecessary; you can bind mount without it
# (2) Unicode quotes don't parse correctly
# (3) You shouldn't need to use this system directory at all
VOLUME [ “/sys/fs/cgroup” ]
```

Deleting that line will cause the anonymous volumes to not get generated, and won't affect the way you run the container.

If you really need to list out the volume IDs, you need to include some whitespace inside the template to get a space-separated list of IDs.

```sh
# Note the space after {{.Name}}
docker inspect \
  -f '{{range .Mounts}}{{if eq .Type "volume"}}{{.Name}} {{end}}{{end}}' \
  33623ebfece7
```

Comment: The docker inspect command worked and gave the correct list. the `docker rm -v 33623ebfece7` didn't deleted the volumes as I expected. I don't know if it's a bug. (and if I should open an issue on Docker's Github)

Comment: I retried after a reboot and cleaning everything before restarting my container, it now works with `-v`
Thanks :)